# React How to handle checked and unchecked events for checkbox using typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, checkbox, react-redux

Hi I am new to React and typescript. I am working on adding checked attribute for a checkbox but find it tricky. I searched across SO but still couldn't get it closer to working.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I am creating three checkbox components using a single child component[shown here]. They all have their own values that I need to pass dynamically.

```
interface ItemProps {
  readonly className?: string;
  readonly checked: boolean | undefined;
  readonly accentedUnchecked?: boolean;
  readonly imageUrl: string;
  readonly errorMessage?: string;
  readonly statusChecked?: boolean | undefined;
  readonly onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  readonly handleClick: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void; 
  };

  readonly hasError?: boolean;
  readonly title?: string;
  readonly value?: number;
  readonly description?: React.ComponentType;
}
export class Item extends React.Component<
  ItemProps,
  {
    readonly isExpanded: boolean;
    readonly checkboxStatus: boolean;
    readonly temp: boolean;
    readonly checked: boolean;    
  }
> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isExpanded: false,
      checkboxStatus: false,
      temp: false,
      checked: this.state.temp
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);    
  }`

  private onChange(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {   
    this.setState({ temp: e.currentTarget.checked });
  }

  private readonly handleClick = e =>
    this.props.onChange({
      currentTarget: { checked: e.currentTarget.checked }
    } as any);

  render() {

    const unchecked = this.props.accentedUnchecked && this.props.checked === false;

    return (

<label className="checkbox">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.onChange} //Not working
            onChange={this.props.onChange}
            onClick={this.handleClick}

            id={"test"}
            data-id="0"
          />
);
```

The problem is I am not sure how to set the checked attribute, based onClick. when I use

```
checked={this.props.checked}
```

I am getting all checkboxes checked. Or if I use

```
checked={this.handleClick}
```

I get error saying

> cannot assign void to a boolean" in typescript.

Any suggestion on how this can be resolved will be very helpful

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

If you want to be quick, online demo has been added at the bottom. I rewrite almost all those stuff.

---

Some notice points:

- Since you want to reuse the child checkbox, you shouldn't write the handler functions inside the child, expose then to parents instead.
- Both `onClick - MouseEvent` and `onChange - ChangeEvent` would be fine since it's fully controlled, the only thing we need to pass is its id. The checked status is held by the parents.
- You can write nested checked logic inside the child, based on the props passed from parents.

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  { id: 1, checked: 1 },
  { id: 2, checked: 0 },
  { id: 3, checked: 1 }
];

export default function App() {
  const [checkedList, setCheckedList] = React.useState(
    data.map(x => !!x.checked)
  );
  const onChangeHandler = (
    e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    id: number
  ) => {
    const list = [...checkedList];
    list.splice(id - 1, 1, !list[id - 1]);
    setCheckedList(list);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Checkboxes</h1>
      {data.map((item, idx) => (
        <InsuranceItem
          id={item.id}
          key={item.id}
          checked={checkedList[idx]}
          onChange={onChangeHandler}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

interface InsuranceItemProps {
  readonly id?: number;
  readonly className?: string;
  readonly checked: boolean | undefined;
  readonly accentedUnchecked?: boolean;
  readonly imageUrl?: string;
  readonly errorMessage?: string;
  readonly statusChecked?: boolean | undefined;
  readonly onChange: (
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>,
    id: number
  ) => void;
  // readonly handleClick: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
  readonly hasError?: boolean;
  readonly title?: string;
  readonly value?: number;
  readonly description?: React.ComponentType;
}
class InsuranceItem extends React.Component<
  InsuranceItemProps,
  {
    // readonly isExpanded: boolean;
    // readonly checkboxStatus: boolean;
    // readonly temp: boolean;
    // readonly checked: boolean;
  }
> {
  constructor(props: InsuranceItemProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // isExpanded: false,
      // checkboxStatus: false,
      // checked: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { id = 0, accentedUnchecked, checked, onChange } = this.props;
    // const unchecked = accentedUnchecked && checked === false;

    return (
      <label className="checkbox">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={e => onChange(e, id)}
          id={id.toString()}
          data-id="0"
        />
      </label>
    );
  }
}
```

### [image]

[image: Edit vigilant-http-zrbx5]

Answer (score 0):

Actually you will not needed `onClick` prop here, and `checked` prop is only expect boolean value

As per react docs, this should be the right way if you have multiple check boxes

```
 handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.name === 'isGoing' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
          [name]: value
        });
      }

    <input
       name="isGoing"
       type="checkbox"
       checked={this.state.isGoing}
       onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Mistake 1

You're setting function instead of boolean for `checked`. Which is wrong. I don't know how TypeScript is allowing you to do that

#### Mistake 2

Using `onClick()` and `onChange()` together. Don't do that. Use only one. Prefer `onChange()` to `onClick()` here.

#### Corrected code

```
// Parent Component
handleClick = (checked: boolean, id: string) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({ 
    checked: { ...prevState.checked, [id]: checked }
  })) // or however you structured this state
}


// Child component
// Creating ID as variable 
const id = 'test';

handleClick = ev => {
  // Avoid passing `ev` directly
  this.props.handleClick(ev.currentTarget.value, id)
}

return (
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={this.props.checked}
            onChange={this.handleClick}
            id={id}
            data-id="0"
          />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `MCheckbox`

import :

```
import { MCheckbox } from '../@material-extend';
```

function :

```
    function handleLike(e) {

    if (e.target.checked) {
    // your code here when it checked
    } else {
     //your code here when it is not checked
    } 
  }
```

jsx :

```
          <MCheckbox
            onChange={(e) => handleLike(e)}
            defaultChecked={false}
            size="small"
            color="error"
            icon={<Icon icon={heartFill} />}
            checkedIcon={<Icon icon={heartFill} />}
          />
```